# Is there any alternative to MediaStreamType.photo to get photo stream in winforms or WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, uwp, webcam

In UWP, to get photostream(not videostream), I use like below.

```
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<IMediaEncodingProperties> res = this.mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo);

await this.mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, res[0]);
```

However, I cannot find any alternative of it in winforms or WPF.
I keep trying to get photo not video snapshot from webcam.

Any comment will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The api mediaCapture can be used from desktop app, see the api description page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture

You will find this attribute:DualApiPartitionAttribute

So to use UWP api from desktop app, see This [Use UWP API in desktop app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance).